# Acer Aspire ES1 311 freezes regularly on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10

Tags: acer, aspire-one

I have upgraded the kernel to linux 4.2.5-040205-generic,this problem will not cease to bug me

I am currently running my laptop on the nomodeset kernel parameter,and am not able to do anything worthwhile on my laptop

Answer (score 1):

I spent a day and a half getting my Aspire E5-511 to run *any* of 14.x, 15.x, 16.04 without freezing (sometimes during install.)  Even when the system runs properly it never powers itself off properly on shutdown.

After much googling and experimentation, I found a fix - 
   The kernel doesn't matter.   The freeze can show up on about any kernel (including the old 4.1.12)

A few boot parameters will fix it completely.

You need to set:

```
  intel_idle.max_cstate=0
  processor.max_cstate=1
  modprobe.blacklist=dw_dmac,dw_dmac_core
```

If your system boots at all, edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.  Replace **every occurence** of :

```
quiet splash  --
```

With this:

```
quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=0 processor.max_cstate=1 modprobe.blacklist=dw_dmac,dw_dmac_core --
```

Now do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and you should be good to go. If your system doesn't get this far - if it hangs while trying to boot up, do a fresh install. Here's a walkthrough (from Windows.):

I grabbed the 14.04 LTs 64-bit ISO file. The 64-bit version is key in that it supports the UEFI file system.  I suspect this solution works for later releases, but haven't yet tried them.

I used Rufus http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-rufus-to-create-a-bootable-usb-drive-to-install-almost-any-os/ to make a bootable thumb drive from the ISO file.  (On windows, you might need to right-click the file and run as Administrator.)   When it asks if you want to do a file-write (default) or a DD data dump, accept the default of file-write.   This allows you to edit the file system on the thumb drive.

Open a file explorer, open the thumb drive, and locate the file boot/grub/grub.cfg.   Now make sure File Explorer is set to "show file extension" (for instance, on Windows 10 - http://www.file-extensions.org/article/show-and-hide-file-extensions-in-windows-10.  Google your OS if otherwise.)

Rename grub.cfg to grub.txt (right-click/Properties).   Double-click the file and open with notepad.

Make the text substitutions described above.

Rename grub.txt back to grub.cfg.

Reboot. Hit F-12 to bring up boot menu. Boot from the thumb drive.
You should get a working system now.

If your system hangs when trying to boot from the thumb-drive, you can add those boot parameters from the Grub menu.  (Can someone knowledgeable give the instructions for this?)

Please excuse all the detail, I wanted to make this information accessible to the broadest possible set of users, given that it's a distro-killing extinction event of a bug on this class of hardware.

I'd be interested to hear if this works for later distros as well, I suspect it does (since they all failed in the same way.)

I also had some mouse problems till I went into BIOS and set Main/touch to Basic.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it worked for me on my Acer E5-511 (same problem on 15.10 and now 16.04). Soemthing to do with Intel power saving regime for laptops, I suspect. 4 days free of crashes (also no shutdown problems any more)

[Ubuntu 15.10 freezes on Acer Aspire E11](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689617/ubuntu-15-10-freezes-on-acer-aspire-e11?rq=1)