# Random temporary freezes on Acer Swift 3 SF314-56-35xs N17W7

Tags: laptop, freeze, acer

I just bought an Acer Swift 3 SF314-56-35xs model N17W7 and installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (kernel 5.0.0-29-generic).

It works, but every 5 minutes or so, **the whole system freezes temporarily**. I can move the mouse pointer, but nothing is responsive. Nothing happens when I click or type on the keyboard. UI is completely frozen.

After like 2 minutes, the system unfreezes, and key presses etc "catch up".

`dmesg` gives the following output:

```
...
nvme nvme0: I/O 493 QID 1 timeout, completion polled
nvme nvme0: I/O 837 QID 3 timeout, completion polled
nvme nvme0: I/O 348 QID 4 timeout, completion polled
...
```

and things like

```
...
systemd-journald.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating
snapd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating
snapd.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Failed to start Journal Service.
Failed to start Snappy daemon.
...
```

Based on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/779606/18623) I've tried adding the following `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` parameters...

```
intel_idle.max_cstate=0
processor.max_cstate=1
modprobe.blacklist=dw_dmac,dw_dmac_core
```

...but the problem with temporary freezes persists.

Any idea what the freezes could be due to would be greatly appreciated.

**Specs:**
Processor: i3-8145U
Graphics: UHD Graphics 620

[Full specs](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/NX.H4CEK.003)

---

**Update:**
The dmesg output repeats over and over, but seem to only start being generated after suspend/resume.