# Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot, even after finishing boot-repair

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, uefi

I have recently re-installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my **Acer Aspire ES1-432** laptop, and have successfully run boot-repair without any problems, though GRUB won't show up, even after performing the recommended tasks to fix this issue. [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fYYhFd37jg/) is the link that boot-repair gave me after successfully finishing it.

I'm a beginner in Linux, so if you can, please explain the steps in layman's terms, or link tutorials. Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you have only one install, grub menu is not normally shown, it just starts boot. But you show "unknown" entries in UEFI menu, those often need "trust" setting with Acer. Some also suggest using rEFInd. Acer Aspire ES1-512-C39M Details on supervisor password and settings to enable trust on ubuntu entries Also R14 model same fix
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256083&p=13203044#post13203044 & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2290594 Boot Parameter required
http://askubuntu.com/questions/695805/acer-aspire-es1-311-freezes-regularly-on-ubuntu-gnome-15-10

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, there is no "Select an Uefi file as trusted for executing" option in my BIOS even after setting a supervisor password and turning on secure boot, and I have tried your suggestion to install rEFInd, but no luck. Is there any way I can add a UEFI file trusted for executing inside the terminal of Linux?

Comment: I have seen a variety of posts with various models of Acer ES1's. But most have been able to make it work. Some systems will boot a hard drive/fallback entry. That just like the external drive entry which is at /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Grub now adds that folder/file. Can you boot the drive? Some only booting Ubuntu use the Windows UEFI boot entry  description which seems to automatically work, but boot Ubuntu. ` sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"` Not recommended if dual booting Windows as grub only boots working Windows and then you have no way to boot it.